# CakePHP - Use JQuery/Ajax to increment an entry in the Db and update a DIV with the result

Tags: cakephp

First all, I am still learning CakePHP and I am close to ZERO using JQuery.

I would like to get help for the following problem I am having:

1. I have an Articles_Controller a Comments_Controller and Users_Controller
2. Currently my articles_controller display an article and its comments are loaded on that page
3. Whoever user inputted the comment will also appear along with his/her image
4. On each comment I have added a like/dislike button.

Example: [image: Comment Screenshot]

Right now, however, I am only able to display it. What I wanted to accomplish is to use JQuery so that when a user clicks on the Thumbs Up or Thumbs Down image the like and disliked fields are automatically updated in the Db. Also, using JQuery I would like to update those same values in the View. Please my code below and thank you for your help.

**articles/view.ctp**

```
<div id="articles_comments">

                    <p>
            Comments
        </p>
        <?php
            foreach($comments as $comment){
        ?>
        <div id="articles_comments_user">
            <img src="<?php echo $comment['User']['image']; ?>">
            <p>
            <?php
                $created = $comment['Comment']['created'];
                echo $comment['User']['first_name'];
                echo "&nbsp;";
                echo $comment['User']['last_name'];
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                //echo $comment['Comment']['created'];
                echo $this->Time->timeAgoInWords(
                    $comment['Comment']['created'], 
                    array(
                        'end'=>'+150 years'
                    )
                );

            ?>
            <p>
        </div>
        <div id="articles_comments_comment">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:85%">
                        <?php echo $comment['Comment']['comment'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:15%;border-left:solid thin teal;">
                        <div style="float:left;">
                            <?php echo $comment['Comment']['liked'];?>
                            <img width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-up-icon.png"
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right;margin-left:10px;">
                            <?php echo $comment['Comment']['disliked'];?>
                            <img width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-down-icon.png">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        <div class="articles_add_comment" id="formUpdateID">
            <hr style="width:100%"><br>

            <div style="float:left">
                <h3>Seu Commentario:</h3> 

            <?php
            echo $form->create(
                     'Comment',
                     array(
                           'url'=>array(
                                'controller'=>'articles',
                                'action'=>'view',
                                $article['Article']['id']
                                ),
                           'class' => 'articles_form',
                           'id' => 'loginForm'
                           )
                     );
            echo $form->input(
                'Comment.comment',
                array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'div' => 'articles_comments_textarea',
                    'cols' => 90,
                    'rows' => 3
                    )
                );
            ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right">

            <?php
                echo $this->Form->submit(
                             'Send',
                             array(
                                   'class' => 'articles_comments_button'
                                   )
                            );
                echo $form->end();
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="ajax-save-message">
                <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Comments is generated from the Articles View action**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by the following upon some research and try outs:

View file

```
<?php foreach $commments as $commment{ ?>

// .............................................................................

<td style="vertical-align:middle;border-left:solid thin teal;padding-left:5px;">
<div class="voteup" style="margin-left:10px;float:left;width:55px;">
    <p style="display:none;float:left">
        <?php echo $comment['Comment']['id']; ?>
    </p>
    <div style="float:left" id="article_thumbsUp">
        <?php echo $comment['Comment']'liked'];?>           
        </div>                                                      
        <img width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-up-icon.png">
</div>
    <div class="votedown" style="float:left;width:55px;">
    <p style="display:none;float:left">
        <?php echo $comment['Comment']['id']; ?>
    </p>
    <div style="float:left" id="article_thumbsDown">
        <?php echo $comment['Comment']'disliked'];?>                                
    </div>                      
    <img width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-down-icon.png">
</div>
</td>

// ...............................................................................

<?php } ?>
```

jQuery I used

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".voteup").click(function() {
        var Id = $(this).children("p").text();
        $(this).children("#article_thumbsUp").load("/comments/voteup/"+Id);
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".votedown").click(function() {
        var Id = $(this).children("p").text();
        $(this).children("#article_thumbsDown").load("/comments/votedown/"+Id);
    });
});
</script>
```

And both of my actions in my `comments_controller.php`

```
function voteUp($id = null){    
    $this->autoRender = false; 
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if($this->Comment->saveField('liked',$this->Comment->field('liked')+1)){
        }
    }       
    $newValue =  $this->Comment->findById($id);     
    return $newValue['Comment']['liked'];
}

function voteDown($id = null){  
    $this->autoRender = false;  
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if($this->Comment->saveField('disliked',$this->Comment->field('disliked')+1)){      
        }
    }       
    $newValue =  $this->Comment->findById($id);     
    return $newValue['Comment']['disliked'];        
}
```

This is my entire code in detail and hopefully it can help someone else. This is the way I know how to do, and if you have any better way, I was be glad to know. Thanks a lot. THIS WORKS GREAT. I JUST NEED TO ADD A FEW MORE THINGS TO THIS SYSTEM, SUCH AS ONLY ALLOW REGISTERED USERS TO VOTE AND ONLY ONCE PER COMMENT. THAT WILL INVOLVE CREATING ANOTHER TABLE TO TRACK THAT.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create actions in the Comments_Controller, `voteup` and `votedown`. Then, make the thumbs up and thumbs down images link to `/comments/voteup/id`, etc.

After doing this, use jQuery to prevent a page reload when they're clicked, as such...

```
<a class="voteup" href="<?php echo $this->base;?>/comments/voteup/<?php echo $comment['Comment']['id'];?>">
    <img ... />
</a>

<script>
    $(".voteup").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href),
            success: function() {
                // Update vote counter
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm sure you can piece together the rest.

Comment: thanks alot for this. I have created the action as you suggested and it able to voteUP/voteDown upon clicking. However, the JQuery magic does not work. As I said before, my knowledge of JQuery is very limited, as I am trying to learn it.I am using the following code in my voteUp action

Comment: if ($id) {
   $this->Comment->id = $id;
   $this->Comment->saveField('liked', $this->Comment->field('liked') + 1);
  }

Comment: And if there is no $id I redirect to the Articles/index

Comment: Just to add, When I click the ThumbsUP image, the link correctly upVotes that comment, but then it forwards me to the voteUp view with an error that the view is not available. I am not looking to see that, but just the value updated...