# Like counting on a post using cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp-2.0

I have two model User(id,username,password),Post(id,user_id,body,created,liked,disliked),if any user like or dislike a post, i want to show total number of like or dislike. i implementet it using  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563719/3792730) it did not worked for me, please somebody tell me how can i do it ?

this is my Post controller:

```
function voteUp($id = null) {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        if ($this->Post->saveField('liked', $this->Post->field('liked') + 1)) {

        }
    }
    $newValue = $this->Post->findById($id);
    return $newValue['post']['liked'];
}

function voteDown($id = null) {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        if ($this->Post->saveField('disliked', $this->Post->field('disliked') + 1)) {

        }
    }
    $newValue = $this->Post->findById($id);
    return $newValue['Post']['disliked'];
}
```

This is my posts/view file :

```
<div class="voteup" style="margin-left:10px;float:left;width:55px;">
    <p style="display:none;float:left">
        <?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>
    </p>
    <div style="float:left" id="article_thumbsUp">
        <?php echo $post['Post']['liked']; ?>           
    </div>                                                      
    <img width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-up-icon.png">
</div>
<div class="votedown" style="float:left;width:55px;">
    <p style="display:none;float:left">
        <?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>
    </p>
    <div style="float:left" id="article_thumbsDown">
        <?php echo $post['Post']['disliked']; ?>                                
    </div>                      
    <img width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-down-icon.png">
</div>
```

this is my js like file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".voteup").click(function() {
            var Id = $(this).children("p").text();
            $(this).children("#article_thumbsUp").load("/posts/voteup/" + Id);
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".votedown").click(function() {
            var Id = $(this).children("p").text();
            $(this).children("#article_thumbsDown").load("/posts/votedown/" + Id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Uhhhh.. If possible, just post the code that's relevant to your needs. It's quite hurty hurt hurt to the eyes.

Comment: Which bit isn't working, and which bit is? You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: it shows only like and unlike icon under a post, but there is no link and nothing happens if i click on icon. if any user like or dislike a post my first target is to show the total number of like/dislike then if possible their username.

Comment: What doesnt work? VoteUP or VoteDown or Both?

Comment: Check the javascript console in your browser to see if the request is being made and what answer you get

Comment: @AKKA-Web , I told in my previous comment, it show the icons only

Comment: @kaklon from Firebug it says SyntaxError: syntax error  
<script>
like.js (line 1), but from my point of view it looks ok.

Comment: @user3792730 so there's your problem, your jquery script is not executing